# How to pick target server for Migrating an application from JBoss 4.0.4?

Tags: java, jboss, migration, wildfly

I am looking for the reasoning which version of JBOSS or WILDFLY I should choose for migration. Can somebody tell I should go for JBOSS AS5 but not JBOSS AS7 or even WILDFLY 8. My application is using EJB 3 and struts 1.2.8 with EAR packaging.

Comment: Does your application have CMP entity beans?

Comment: No Steve It's not using them.

Comment: Then I would look at going straight to WildFly 11. It will not be less difficult than the older servers.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but Did you consider this way I have to move Major version for Application Server , J2EE, and JDK as well. However in my research I found official docs and blogs for moving from JBOSS 4 to 5 but nothing at all for Wildfly. However there is a official docs to move from AS5 to wildfly.

Comment: There's almost nothing to do for JBoss 4 -> 5 migration.The same application will run in JBoss 5 with very little modification.

Comment: Now it make sense to move to Wildfly thanks for the help. If you can Point me to some Article/Blogs or steps that would be wonderful :)

Answer (score 1):

You should ask yourself which are the reasons why you want to migrate.

- Did you hit a critical bug?
- Do you need new features?
- Do you need support?

JBoss 4 and 5 rather similar, but both outdated. Support for EAP5 ended 2013. You won't get much community-support either. If I decide I had to migrate, i would migrate to the latest EAP or stable WildFly version depending on the needs for support.

Comment: Siegl yes the big reason for us is these software's are outdated and not supported anymore. The best option is see so far is Wildfly. I got afraid cause lot of people  suggested that we gotta migrate major version for JDK, j2ee and other third party libraries.  that's why I cared to ask.